# how to set dots using uiimage or uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here i have some json data like bone = 24. based on this json value i have to change some small dots to big dots as i show in my below image.

[image]

Like my above image . (please consider image 1). it have 10 big dots. And based on that bone.label value i have to change some big dots to small dots.

My doubt is:

1. How to set that dot image using (uiimage or uibutton). my idea is to set 10 uiimage and then using if statement condition i will change big dots to small dots. but if i do in this way i am not able to set constraints. is they any other idea to dots in above my cirecle??

Comment: the simplest way - flip animation, using the set of png images

Comment: please can u explain me what to do flip animation . and here what you mention the set of image

Comment: here the tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-animation-uiimageview/

Comment: Please get my question. i din't ask to show any animation. what i need is : i have to set some uimage or uibutton on round of circle. based on my label.text value some of mybig dots should change to small dots. Thats what i need. i have doubt in how to set uimage or uibutton in round manner with eeual constraints. or any other idea

Comment: it's no standard animation like this, you should make yourself and as I mention, the simplest way - draw the set of the images. Also it wasn't the answer, it's just a comment to show you the way how to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Do it in code, not in Interface builder, and without constraints. I doubt that working with circular relations is working well with autolayout constraints.

If you position the dot images with their center instead of the frame, their location is also not changing with their size.

Comment: that means i have to set uiimage as in circle way without IB. for example my uiimage (dot image size is) = 10 X 10. Then its is possible to make it as a circle manner( like my above image dot circle).? How can i set the position of uiimage  in circle way ?. and too if i set the position. sure it will differ for other screen size>>

Answer (score 0):

Use the same size for all of your UIImageViews and then just change the image to a small or large dot. Set the content mode of the UIImageViews to center, so that the images won't be scaled to fit the size of the UIImageView.

UPDATE

You could solve the positioning of the dots by drawing them in a UIView instead of using constraints. Here's a function that returns an array with CGPoints evenly distributed around a circle, which you could use when drawing the dots:

```
func generatePoints(totalPoints: Int, center: CGPoint, radius: Double) -> [CGPoint] {
    let arc: Double = 360
    let startAngle: Double = 180
    let mpi: Double = M_PI/180
    var startRadians: Double = startAngle * mpi
    let incrementAngle: Double = arc/Double(totalPoints)
    let incrementRadians = incrementAngle * mpi

    var points = [CGPoint]()
    var currentPoint = totalPoints
    while currentPoint > 0 {
        currentPoint--
        let xp = CGFloat(ceil(Double(center.x) + sin(startRadians) * radius))
        let yp = CGFloat(ceil(Double(center.y) + cos(startRadians) * radius))
        points.append(CGPointMake(xp, yp))
        startRadians -= incrementRadians
    }
    return points;
}
```

Objective-C version (somewhat ugly, because it's from an ooooooold project of mine):

```
+ (NSArray*)generatePoints:(NSInteger)totalPoints center:(CGPoint)center radius:(NSInteger)radius {

    float circleradius = (float)radius;    
    const float arc = 360.f;
    float startAngle = 180.f;

    float mpi = M_PI/180.f;
    float startRadians = startAngle * mpi;
    float incrementAngle = arc/(float)totalPoints;
    float incrementRadians = incrementAngle * mpi;

    NSMutableArray *pts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:totalPoints];

    while (totalPoints--) {
        float xp = ceilf(center.x + sinf(startRadians) * circleradius);
        float yp = ceilf(center.y + cosf(startRadians) * circleradius);
        [pts addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xp, yp)]];
        startRadians -= incrementRadians;
    }

    return pts;
}
```

Comment: yes i did this way. but seeting constraint is very hard . if i have 10 image means like 10 X 10 means . while run in other 6,6s simulator. my uimage are collapsed . hard to set constraints in this way.

Comment: really sorry i am zero in swift. haven't start to learn. can you do with objective c

Comment: OK, I added an obj-c version

Comment: i understood what you saying, now i create 10 image and added your code in my project. but still my 10 uiimage are not in perfect circle manner.

Comment: my uiview size is now 141 x 161. and my 10 uiimage size is 8 X 8. i added your code. but how can i change to work.please guid me

Comment: in your code i am getting error at last `}` bracket .error is: `control reaches of non vide function`. and in your code where i will add my uiview name

Comment: Sorry, I forget a return statement at the end of the function. I updated the code. My code only returns an array with points that tell you where the images should be drawn. You will then have to create a subclass of UIView where you will use the array to draw your images at these points. You do not add UIImageViews, instead you draw the images in the UIView's drawRect method. You should be able to find info on how to draw images pretty easily.

Comment: i am not handled this type to create a uiview draeRect method. please  gudie me to do that. i added your code. after that i created a new class called` dotviewimage` which subclass of uiview. and in that i created a method `void drawRect`. what to code inside that method for 10 dots.if i do in this way it is possible to change the big dot to small dot based on my json value?